# Why am I getting a index error for my loop in python?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, feature-extraction

I am trying to divide a raw image into 8x8 overlapping blocks so I can do feature extraction later.

Here is my code:

```
new0 = np.zeros((heightimage0R, widthimage0R), np.uint8)
k = 0
for i in range(heightimage0R):
    for j in range(widthimage0R):
        crop_tmp0R = image0R[i:i+8,j:j+8]
        new0[k, 0:64] = crop_tmp0R.flatten()
        k = k + 1
```

However, when ever I run my code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-392-cf9c59842d3a>", line 6, in <module>
    new0[k, 0:64] = crop_tmp0R.flatten()

IndexError: index 256 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 256
```

I have tried `widthimage0R-1` in the for loop but it still does not work.

Comment: `widthimage0R` is probably 1 too large, try `widthimage0R - 1` in the for loop.

Comment: I also tried that, it did not work unfortunately!

Comment: `k = 0` should probably be written after `for i ...` as you'll notice the value of k will go to `heightimage0R` * `widthimage0R` the way it is written.

Comment: `8 X 8 overlapping blocks` -> what does this mean?   Can you specify exactly how much overlap/exactly what size (either in pixel number or relative to image size)

Comment: `i+8` will be at most `heightimage0R + 8`, which is out of bounds of an array of size `heightimage0R`. You probably only want to only iterate `for i in range(heightimage0R-8):`. The same is true for `j`.

Comment: I just tried `for i in range(heightimage0R-8):
    for j in range(widthimage0R-8):`  but I still got the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new0` is of size `heightimage0R`x`widthimage0R` (which I'll refer to as `h`x`w` for now), which I assume is the same size of `image0R` (otherwise you have more problems).

What your code is doing is taking a 8x8 square from `image0R` and flattening it into the new array.

The problem arises because `new0` is a `h`x`w`-matrix, but you're using it as a `h*w`x`64`-matrix. This is because the row has value `k`, which goes between 0 to `h*w`, and the column is always 64.

My guess is that you mean to do the following:

```
new0 = np.zeros((heightimage0R*widthimage0R, 64), np.uint8)
k = 0
for i in range(heightimage0R-8):  # Don't forget the -8 to not exceed the size of the image0R as well!
    for j in range(widthimage0R-8):
        crop_tmp0R = image0R[i:i+8,j:j+8]
        new0[k, 0:64] = crop_tmp0R.flatten()
        k = k + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new0 = np.zeros((heightimage0R, widthimage0R), np.uint8)
```

Here, `new0` is of shape `heightimage0R` x `widthimage0R`.

```
for i in range(heightimage0R):
    for j in range(widthimage0R):
        crop_tmp0R = image0R[i:i+8,j:j+8]
        new0[k, 0:64] = crop_tmp0R.flatten()
```

Here we are trying to access k'th row of `new0` where k goes up to (`heightimage0R` x `widthimage0R`). So after k crosses `heightimage0R`, it must be throwing error.

Can you be more specific of what you want to achieve? Looks like the logic needs to be changed.

Comment: I am trying to write a code to divide an image into sliding blocks of 8x8 pixels and then transform them to vectors of size 64. I believe the "step size" should only be 1. After the vectors have been created I want to assign a label to all the vectors with 0.